# Dapper dynamic parameters throw a SQLException "must define scalar variable" when not using anonymous objects

Tags: c#, sqlexception, dapper

(This code is using Dapper Dot Net in C#)

This code works:

```
var command = "UPDATE account SET priority_id = @Priority WHERE name = @Name";
connection_.Execute(command, new { Name = "myname", Priority = 10 } );
```

This code throws a SqlException:

```
class MyAccount 
{
    public string Name;
    public int Priority;
}

var command = "UPDATE account SET priority_id = @Priority WHERE name = @Name";
var acct = new MyAccount { Name = "helloworld", Priority = 10 };
connection_.Execute(command, acct);
```

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Must declare the scalar variable "@Priority".

Why?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Implement your model with properties, not fields:

```
class MyAccount 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
}
```

Dapper looks at the properties of the object to get parameters, ignoring fields. Anonymous types work because they are [implemented with properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx?ppud=4).

Comment: Interesting; we consider fields for the materialization, so maybe it is a little inconsistent that we don't allow then (public ones, at least), for parameterisation. Meh... You're right though - trivial to solve by correct use of properties.

Comment: @MarcGravell it does seem to violate the principle of least surprise. I'd vote to either change the behavior or document the requirement.

Comment: Be sure to use "public" properties else you get the "must define scalar variable" error when you use "internal" or "private" properties.

Answer (score 2):

Although this answer doesn't relate to the poster's issue, I had a similar problem with a different fix that I'll share here.

I was incorrectly defining the parameter list as a `new []{ ... }`:

```
var name = "myName";
var priority = 1;
var command = "UPDATE account SET priority_id = @Priority WHERE name = @Name";
connection_.Execute(command, new []{ priority, name });
```

Dropping the `[]` solved my issue:

```
connection_.Execute(command, new { priority, name });
```

Answer (score 1):

I also got a same problem with data type. When make a query with dynamic object that has a DateTime property, exception: The member CreatedDate of type System.Object cannot be used as a parameter value.

It worked when I used a POCO instead of dynamic later.